# drawing different point sizes for each labels

Tags: plot, gnuplot

How can I define different point sizes for different labels. For example, the labels are

```
100
200
300
```

I want to define a map that draw a point with `ps 1` for 100, `ps 2` for 200 and `ps 3` for 300.

How that is possible in Gnuplot?

**UPDATE**

The data file looks like

```
 100 NaN 100
 NaN 200 NaN
 300 200 NaN
```

I have this command to exclude NaN

```
 symbol(N) = strcol(N) ne "NaN" ? strcol(N) : " "
```

As a result `:(symbol(N)*0.1) with points ps var` is incorrect

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That can be done with `pointsize variable`. That uses the values of an additional column for the point size:

```
plot 'file.dat' using 0:1:($1*0.01) pointsize variable
```

For your updated data file, you don't need to use `strcol`, `NaN` is ignored when treated as numerical value:

```
symbol(N) = strcol(N) ne "NaN" ? strcol(N) : " "
unset key
set offset 0.2,0.2,0.2,0.2
plot for [i=1:3] 'file.dat' using (i-1):0:(symbol(i)) with labels offset char 0,1,\
         'file.dat' matrix using 1:2:($3*0.01) with points pt 7 ps var lt 1
```

[image]

Comment: Problem is the numbers are considered as strings hence ($1*0.01) is incorrect. Let me update the post